# Ember 1.8.1- component link-to not working with action

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am using Ember 1.8.1. I have a component for some notifications. They use dynamic variables to determine a link-to ( I use computed properties to determine the proper route, and model to send through. This is calculating correctly.). Then within the link-to an action is defined.

```
{{#link-to event.routeName event.routeTarget}}
      <li {{action "eventClick" event}}>
            ..other markup...
      </li>
{{/link-to}}
```

Everything was working before I moved these into a component. My problem now is that while the action works, and the URL is being properly formed (on hover I can see that I have the correct URL that my link-to should be creating), when I click on the link in the UI, the action fires, but the link does not transition as it is supposed to.

I've dealt with the opposite problem before - actions within a link-to not working correctly, but never the problem this way. Is there something obvious I am missing? I've searched through the documentation and can't seem to find anything that tells me what I'm doing is wrong.

Recap: In my Ember component, why does the routing for the link-to not work, but the action within it does? Again- this all worked before making it a component, so I'm not sure what the difference is.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you duplicate your issue here? http://emberjs.jsbin.com/balana/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Hm. This seems to work just fine. I'm not sure what the difference is between this and what my code is. I've edited it slightly to be more like what I'm doing, but now I'm going through my code to attempt to figure out what is different and why mine won't work. Edited jsbin: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/subihepono/1/edit?html,js,console,output